# How to align a view in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, fragment

this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/photos"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ds" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/navigation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I want to make it like below:

[image: GUI]

Could you advice me, how can I align this elements?
What should be in `Linear`, what in `Relative?`
I will use this GUI for min **API 14**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Relative Layout** is Something like Drop-Down layout.. Means you can put your widget on that layout whenever you want to put.

Just Like **LinearLayout** has a fixed type of Layout. It has a Vertical and Horizontal orientation. You can add your widget to this layout according to your requirenment..

For more info you can get via [this](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-layouts-part-one-linear-and-relative-layouts/)

Answer (score 1):

Your layout possibly should be like this , please add tab layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/photos"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="TextView" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="TextView" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/navigation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/yellow"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                       <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="ajdkad  kadka d  aldjad la dhakd akd akd akdhkadh ad hakdh ad a" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```